Ists and anti-ists
If you hold to the teachings of Calvinism, you are a Calvinist. If you are against the teachings Calvinism, would it be grammatically correct and standard to say you are an anti-Calvinist? Or would saying you are an anti-Calvinist imply that you are against individuals who are Calvinists? More generally, someone is as adherent to X-ism, they are called an X-ist. If someone is opposed to X-ism, is it grammatically correct and standard to call them an anti-X-ist?

It might be taken to imply that you are against the individuals as well as their practice. It would be clear if you say "I do not hold to the teachings of Calvinism", but being against something and not believing it are different things. An anti-X implies determined action.

It seems to be a trend to not used the -ist with anti- these days. If this becomes more formalized, and I think it may, then the -ist form would specifically mean against the people, as opposed to against the -ism. You can avoid the problem by not using these as bare nouns, - anti-Islam propaganda, anti-communism movement. Having said that, anti-communist, anti-socialist, and anti-fascist are deeply rooted in English and resist easy definitions with clear boundaries.

@Weather Vane We're heading for Calvino-sceptic. But I'd stick with your suggestion (though I actually have to believe in both predestination and self-determination).

+1 for @WeatherVane’s comment. And to express it more plainly: The term anti-Calvinist almost invites the interpretation of “person who is opposed to Calvinists,” rather than “person who is opposed to Calvinism.”  And opposition to Calvinism is a stronger position than is mere absence of adherence to Calvinism.

In my opinion, we have a solid opinion-based question here, though that's just my opinion. The OP itself implies that anticapitalism opposes that 'ism' concept, and anticapitalist would oppose that 'ist' person.

There are different degrees of opposition: you can not believe in something, not care about something, actively campaign against it. You can use non- or un- or (with Greek roots) a- for some of these sense.

@StuartF not to mention counter- as in counter terrorist. You can go down the rabbit hole pretty quickly here - talk about ambiguous - https://www.airuniversity.af.edu/Portals/10/ASPJ/journals/Volume-29_Issue-4/F-Munzo_Crosston.pdf

What’s wrong with I am anti-Calvinism?

Being opposed to Calvanists, the people, as opposed to being opposed to Calvinism, the doctrine, for my money makes you an anti-Calvinistist.  Then again, Calvinists are probably going to assume there's some overlap in any case.
